# Can't find Alt-F5 in Settings/Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.10

Eclipse uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to *Update Maven Project*.

It's worked on earlier versions of Ubuntu, but on 20.10 that key combination is mapped to *Un-maximize window*, which is also what <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> does.

I cannot find <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> under Settings → *Keyboard Shortcuts*, and I haven't figured out where these mappings are stored or how to change them outside the Settings app.

Answer (score 15):

"Restore", which is found in the Windows section in Settings - Keyboard shortcuts, is not only assigned to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, but also to the "traditional" shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. You can disable the binding to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and retain the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> binding:

- Go to "Settings" - "Keyboard"
- Click "View and customize shortcuts" in the right pane
- Under the section "Windows", click "Restore window".
- The "Set shortcut" dialog appears.
- Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>: this will set that key only.

Alternatively, use `gsettings` in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize "['<Super>Down']"
```

That removes the assignment to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, but maintains <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> for unmaximizing a window. Reset to the default (`['<Super>Down', '<Alt>F5']`) with the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize
```

You can edit this and many other "hidden" settings using `dconf-editor`, not installed by default.

Comment: I'm going through and mapping modifier+F keys for maximizing capabilities to use in terminal (and unsetting them for gnome) and I found out that you can show that both Alt+F5 and Super+Down are bound to unmaximize by running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize`, it shows: `['<Super>Down', '<Alt>F5']`. I think we can unbind Alt+F5, then, by simply going in and setting it to Super+Down (which seemingly would do nothing but should clear out Alt+F5).

Comment: Use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize "[]"` to remove binding

Comment: thank you! this was breaking with vscode's "move to next/previous change" for me.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it helped. It's even simpler to remove the binding, with just the standard configuration dialog. it's enough to set the binding again to the default value - Super Down. This will set it to just Super Down, removing the binding to Alt F5.

Comment: Did you set the shortcut to Alt F5? I didn't mean to reset it to the default value, btu simply select the Alt+F5 shortcut for it. Maybe it's necessary to set another shortcut for it first, and then set it to Alt F5, but I don't think I had to do it. I simply selected the shortcut and pressed Alt + F5 on the keyboard.

Comment: Of course, I got confused. All the time I meant to set the binding to Super + Down. By default, it appears to be set to Super + Down in the UI, but it's set to both Super + Down and Alt + F5. If you click on the Restore Window setting and just press Super + Down, it will set it to Super + Down only, deleting the binding for Alt + F5. In the UI, you will still see the same Super + Down binding, but with the X button, which wasn't there before.

Comment: Amazing thanks! This should be accepted as answer.